# My Intel Core i3 frequently shuts down due to "Processor Thermal Trip error"

Tags: cooling, intel-core-i3

My Desktop PC running Windows 7 on Intel Core i3 dual processor machine started shutting down during the boot process a couple of days ago. I left it alone for about 48 hours and tried again. The boot process informed me about Processor Thermal Trip as being the cause of boot failures and suggested a Windows recovery process. I went through the recovery process which completed without problems. The PC booted normally and Windows 7 worked as expected but after 10 minutes it again tripped and now whenever I start it, it shuts down during the boot process.

What should I do next?... is there a boot menu / setup  settings that needs to be adjusted to avoid it... Or is there a hardware problem (which seems unlikely as the machine occasionally boots perfectly )?

***UPDATE: Thanks folks for the help . I wasnt confident enough to mess with the PC myself so I took it to my dealer. He fixed the issue. Below is my answer.  Each one of your answers/comments have some truth in it.***

Comment: When was the last time you opened the lid and vacuumed out all the dust?

Answer (score 5):

Is your CPU fan running? Processor Thermal Trip means your CPU is overheating. if there is no fan or its not running, it usually takes about 30sec to 1min for your CPU to overheat in the summer.

Comment: Also:  Check that the fans are causing are to flow through the machine.  I once had a client who installed all their fans to push air out, but there was no way for the air to get in (aside from small holes and very thing cracks in the chassis).  After changing one fan in the front to pull air in (by simply turning it around), their overheating problems were solved.

Answer (score 1):

Check to be sure the heatsink is properly attached to the processor/motherboard and the Fan is operating properly. I would remove the heatsink to check for mounting damage or improper thermal compound application then clean it and the processor and re-apply [IC Diamond 7 thermal compound](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0042IEVD8).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the the suggestions/answers.  I showed it to my dealer. He booted the PC once then switched it off. Opened the case and touched the heat sink. He said its very very hot. He again switched on the PC . The fan was fine. He switched it off , did some vacuum cleaning of the fan and the sink, applied some paste , refitted everything and restarted the PC. There wasn't any Thermal tripping anymore ... I touched the heat sink ... it was cool as cucumber. Now I am typing long comments and answers  from my cool PC  again !!